# Two lucene indexes need two Directory objects?

Tags: java, lucene

If I have two types of documents to index, and I'm using two different lucene indexesm do I need to provide two different `Directory` objects? Does each index require its own directory?

Comment: Well, it depends if you have one or two indexes. Could you add some more details? Some code would be even better.

Comment: sorry, no code here, I am just trying to figure out how to use lucene.
I think my Q title made it clear that I am assuming a two indexes scenario. I do understand that I could index two types of documents within a single index and differentiate between them using some sort of an untokenized "type" filed. I also understand that it might be even a good thing to do if you want to get different types of objects based on a single query (e.g. artists, venues & reviews ). but again my Q is if a single directory can hold several indexes or does each index require its own directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because every `Directory` instance has its own path, and each index must have its own location. You can't have two indexes on the same location.